# In vuetify, how to validate v-time-pickers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js, datetimepicker

I'm using two v-time-pickers in my vuetify project. I want to validate my time-pickers that it'll be impossible to choose on second  time -picker earlier time than on the first time-picker.

For example when on the first time-picker user will choose time: 9am, at second picker it will be impossible to choose hours before 9am and enabled will be hours only from 10am.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers/#dialog-and-menu

Code:

pickers.js

```
    <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="menu2"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="time"
        lazy
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        full-width
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="time"
            label="Picker in menu"
            prepend-icon="access_time"
            readonly
            v-on="on"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
          v-if="menu2"
          v-model="time"
          full-width
          @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(time)"
        ></v-time-picker>
      </v-menu>
    </v-flex>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-flex xs11 sm5>
      <v-dialog
        ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal2"
        :return-value.sync="time"
        persistent
        lazy
        full-width
        width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="time"
            label="Picker in dialog"
            prepend-icon="access_time"
            readonly
            v-on="on"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
          v-if="modal2"
          v-model="time"
          full-width
        >
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal2 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(time)">OK</v-btn>
        </v-time-picker>
      </v-dialog>
```

script.js

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        time: null,
        menu2: false,
        modal2: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
content_copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage allowed-hours and minutes props from the v-time-picker component:

```html
<v-time-picker
      v-if="modal2"
      v-model="time"
      :allowed-hours="allowedHours"
      :allowed-minutes="allowedMinutes"
      full-width
    >
```

and customize your logic in your script :

```js
methods: {
      allowedHours: v => v % 2,
      allowedMinutes: v => v >= 10 && v <= 50
    },
```

Comment: thank you @jcoleau for answer, could you tell me how to relate this validation rules between two timepickers?

Comment: Both time pickers `v-model` are pointing so the same variables (time), is it intended?

Comment: No, it isnt. I want to have option to choose diferent time on pickers and create validation rules between pickers

Comment: Then point the second picker to a second variable `time2` for example and then you can refer to the first variable in your logic `allowedHours: v =>  v >= this.time +1` something like that